# How get cell hyperlink address from Excel?

Tags: excel, qt, activex, qt5, qaxobject

[image]

To read text from cell I use this:

```
QAxObject *e = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");
QAxObject *wbooks = e->querySubObject("Workbooks");
QAxObject *wbook = wbooks->querySubObject("Open(const QString&)", "somefile.xls");
QAxObject *s = wbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);
QVariant v = s->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", 2, 2)->property("Value");
// v = "sometext"
```

But how read hyperlink address from cell?

*Qt 5.0.1 Windows 7*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
QAxObject *e = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");
QAxObject *wbooks = e->querySubObject("Workbooks");
QAxObject *wbook = wbooks->querySubObject("Open(const QString&)", "somefile.xls");
QAxObject *s = wbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);
QVariant v = s->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", 2, 2)->querySubObject("Hyperlinks(int)", 1)->property("Address");
```